# How to convert Json String to Object with Dictionary using JayRock

Tags: c#, json, jayrock

I want to convert a Json string to an Object in C#.
the string is like this:

```
{"dealName":"name1","properties":{"a":"1", "b":"2"}}
```

I define the class like this:

```
public class DealInfo
{
   public string dealName;
   public Dictionary<string, string> properties;
}
```

And I use this code to convert:

```
DealInfo dl = JsonConvert.Import(typeof(DealInfo), jsonString) as DealInfo;
```

I found it just converted the dealName field, but the properties count is 0.
So, what's the problem? How to fix it?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
DealInfo dl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DealInfo>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Thank you! But I wan to convert with jayrock.

Comment: do you mean: (DealInfo)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString, typeof(DealInfo))?