# Dictionary to JSON and JSON to Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, json, dictionary

I have a web apicontroller with a get method which sends an object with a Dictionary to sencha (extjs). The data loads fine to sencha. Now when I post the data back to the controller from sencha, my object (DTOUnivere in example below) gets filled without the list of objects (QualityIndicators below). So the conversion from JSON to dictionary doesn't work?

Controller:

```
[HttpPut]
public void PutUniverse(int id, DTOUniverse dtoUniverse)
{

}
```

JSON output when posted

```
"{
"Name": "Libelle",
"Description": "",
"Domains": "",
"TimeZone": "",
"Script": "",
"DecayPercentage": "0",
"DecayTime": "",
"QualityIndicators": {
    "Age": {
        "Enabled": true,
        "Operator": ">",
        "Value": 80
    },
    "LastActivity": {
        "Enabled": true,
        "Operator": "=",
        "Value": 20
    },
    "Hits": {
        "Enabled": true,
        "Operator": "<>",
        "Value": 15
    },
    "AverageVisitDuration": {
        "Enabled": true,
        "Operator": "<",
        "Value": 10.5
    }
}
```

}"

The problem is that the DTOUniverse.QualityIndicators (the actual dictionary) are null.
How can I convert this JSON back to the dictionary?

Comment: Post the JSON to dictionary code?

Answer (score 1):

Create model in site [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com)

Parse model via Json.net

Answer (score 0):

use [fastjson](http://fastjson.codeplex.com/) it has compatibility to serilize json to dictionary and vice versa

here is the detailed article to use [fastjson](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159450/fastJSON)

Answer (score -1):

In your JSON `QualityIndicators` is not a list (array), it is just a plain object, you need to surround your object with `[]` if you want it to be parsed as an array

Comment: If I do that, I get a List of my Quality Indicators, but it needs to be a dictionary.

Comment: why a Dictionary? what would be the key?

Comment: Age, LastActivity,... are the keys. I need it to be a Dictionary<string, object> where object is QualityIndicator. Sencha requires it this way.

Comment: I understand... take a look at this, it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792007/how-to-convert-json-string-to-object-with-dictionary-using-jayrock